# Lambdify or evaluate CoordSys3D

Tags: python, sympy

### How do I evaluate a point on a Sympy CoordSys3D expression?

**Using the Sympy physics module this process works as expected**:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame, CoordinateSym, divergence
R = ReferenceFrame('R')
field = R[0]*R[1]*R[2]*(R.x+R.y+R.z) 

div = divergence(vect=field, frame=R)
div_func = lambdify([R[0], R[1], R[2]], div, modules='numpy')
print('Function evaluated at a point = {}'.format(div_func(1,2,8)))
```

**However, if I instead use `CoordSys3D` a process to lambdify is not clear:**

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, divergence, curl

A = CoordSys3D('A')  
field = A.x*A.y*A.z*(A.i + A.j + A.k)
div = divergence(field)

# How do I lambdify / evaluate this? 

# This fails:   
#    File "<lambdifygenerated-5>", line 1
#    def _lambdifygenerated(A.x, A.y, A.z):
#    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# div_func = lambdify([A.x, A.y, A.z], div, modules='numpy')

# This fails:
#    "name 'x' is not defined"
# div_func = lambdify([x, y, z], div, modules='numpy')

print('Function evaluated at a point = {}'.format(div_func(1,2,8)))
```

A few observations:

- `R[0]` is a `sympy.physics.vector.frame.CoordinateSym`
- `A.x` is a `sympy.vector.scalar.BaseScalar`

The `CoordSys3D` seems to be the format I'd like, especially since support for spherical coordinate systems is straightforward.

For example:

```
A = CoordSys3D('A', transformation='spherical')  # transformation requires Sympy 1.2 
vec_field = a*A.r**2*A.i + c*cos(A.theta)/A.r*A.j + b * A.k 
div = divergence(vec_field)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `lambdify` does not properly interpret `A.x` when generating code (it should), so you have to replace it by a symbol.

```
vars = symbols('A.x A.y A.z')
div_func = lambdify(vars, div.subs(dict(zip([A.x, A.y, A.z], vars))), modules='numpy')
print(div_func(1, 2, 8))  # 26
```

It does not really matter what the symbols `vars` are called, I named them "A.x" and so on just for consistency. They could be just as well be `vars = symbols('v0:3')`.