# How to calculate the divergent of a vector in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to calculate the divergent of a given vector with `sympy`. Is there any function in python responsible for this? I looked for something in the functions of einsteinpy, but I still haven't found any that help.

Basically I want to calculate `\nabla_\mu (n v^\mu)=0` from a given vector `v`; `n` being a constant number.

`\nabla_\mu (nv^\mu)=0` represents a divergence where `\mu` will take the derivative with respect to `x`, `y` or  `z` of the vector element corresponding to the component. For example:

`\nabla_\mu (n v^\mu) = \partial_x (u^x) + \partial_y(u^y) + \partial_z(u^z)`

`u` can be something like `(2x,4y,6z)`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, can you be a bit more precise in your notation, please. \mu is a scalar? If v is a vector, what is your understanding of a power of that vector.

Comment: Thanks. I added something that can make it clearer

Comment: Hi... do you use the `^` to refer to the vector component? I have the impression that you do not mean `power()`. In that case it would be a simple divergence of a continuous vector field, yes?

Comment: Eventually, I think you are looking for [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/fields.html) the notation is a bit confusing, but is should do what you want

Comment: for numerical evaluation [ this SO post ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484568/lambdify-or-evaluate-coordsys3d) will help

Answer (score 0):

As shown by @mikuszefski, you can use the module `sympy.vector` such that you have the implementation of the divergence in a space.

Another way to do what you want is to use the function `derive_by_array` to get a tensor and do einsten contraction.

```py
import sympy as sp

x, y, z = sp.symbols("x y z")   # dim = 3

# Now the functions that you want:
u, v, w = 2*x, 4*y, 6*z  

# In a more general way, you can do:
u = sp.Function("u")(x, y, z)
v = sp.Function("v")(x, y, z)
w = sp.Function("w")(x, y, z)


U = sp.Array([u, v, w])  # U is a vector of dim = 3 (or sympy.Array)
X = sp.Array([x, y, z])  # X is a vector of dim = 3 (or sympy.Array)

dUdX = sp.derive_by_array(U, X)  # dUdX is a tensor of dim = 3 and order = 2

# Frist way:
divU = sp.trace(sp.Matrix(sp.derive_by_array(U, X)))  # Limited

# Second way:
divU = sp.tensorcontraction(sp.derive_by_array(U, X), (0, 1))  # More general
```

This solution works fine when `dim = 2` for example, but you must have that  `len(X) == len(U)`